# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager with tomcat in Spring hetos

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to create a sample app of `Spring hateos` and struggling with below exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hetos-medias]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hetos-medias]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager;
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.<clinit>(WsWebSocketContainer.java:77)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

it looks like there could be duplicate jar for class `org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager`  but I did not find any duplicate jar in my classpath. I'm using tomcat 7 and below are my `pom.xml` and library details.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>




    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

[image]
[image: Jar in ref lib]

Comment: Are you deploying to a version of Tomcat different from the one you used for compiling?  That is the usual cause of this type of error.  Even if you're "sure" the versions are the same, I'd double check.

Comment: i'm using apache-tomcat-7.0.70 in my eclipse and war is properly synchronized with server. this is only server in my eclipse .

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the following in your pom.xml

```
<tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html